# Find Last Entry in a Given Month

Tags: excel, list, date, vlookup, lookup

I have a sheet that updates from a query, attached example.  The query is formatted so that the dates are from latest to oldest.  I need to pull data from the rows based on the last entry of a specific item that is made each month.  There are multiple entries but I only care about the counts for 'Cross1'.  So I need the last entry for each of these every January, then February, and so on.  This is updated each month.  I was conchatenating the date and the description columns for my VLOOKUP.

Originally, I had no problem using a VLOOKUP that just found the entry based on the last day of the prior month, as there was always an entry on the final day of the month.  However, the users have now changed the data so that it may not update all the way through the month due to breaks, meetings, vacations, etc.  So now my formulas do not work for those months and they will be random.  You can see this in the attachment, which I pulled from halfway through December.  You can see that Cross1 disappears after the 20th.  It has entries for the 21st but the counts are empty.  I need to pull the last entry for each month of Cross1 that has the counts filled in.  In this case, 12/20, NOT 12/21.[image]

I then tried alternatives such as the LOOKUP function which seemed to be what I needed.  However, the function assumes that the data is sorted in the opposite order of my sheet.  So, it works and finds what I need, but in the wrong direction (finds the FIRST entry instead).  I have asked, and cannot change the query data. So that option is out.

This formula works if the data is sorted with the last date at the top: =LOOKUP(2,1/(c$2:c5995=D4786),a$2:a5995).  However, I need to also have it verify that it is the last entry AND there are counts present.  In other words, 12/21 would NOT be the entry I want.  I would want 12/20 in this example.  Thanks to @ronrosenfeld for helping me flesh out my question.

So I am hoping someone has a suggestion.  I can go the VBA route but I was thinking there might be something simpler?

Comment: Where is the formula that you tried and didn't work?  And if you have multiple entries on the same date, how do you know which one is the latest? And I don't see any thing to show what your results might look like. It might help if you take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are the "counts" all-or-none (ie. they're either all there or all empty) ?

Comment: Hi Ron, you know, as I wrote the question I knew the question was vague but was not sure how to make it better.  Thanks to your question, I think I know, so I have added that now to the question and to this comment.  This formula works if the data is sorted with the last date at the top=LOOKUP(2,1/(c$2:c5995=D4786),a$2:a5995).  However, I need to also have it verify that it is the last entry AND there are counts present.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for my question!

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks and yes, all there or empty.  If they do not run, the cells are empty.  No zeroes, nothing.  Just clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using array formulas:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tim, that tells me the rows but how would I use it as a VLOOKUP and pull the data from the counts?

Comment: You'd wrap that in (eg to get the count from ColC) `=INDEX(C:C, [arrayformulahere])`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the past couple of hours and cannot get your method to work.  I am thinking that you may have inserted a column and the values moved over as E2 is blank above?  I compensated, but still just get a #VALUE! error.  This is an array formula so I would need the ctrl+shift+enter as well, right?

Comment: What I showed above was just an example - it's likely not going to copy/paste to your specific worksheet.  Your screenshot has no column/row headers, so I created my own sample data.   If you can share a sample workbook I will try to set up an example in that.

Comment: Tim, thanks, I am still trying to figure this out but still not getting to the end.  How do I share a sample wkbk on here?  I can do pictures but do not see how to do an actual file.  Thanks

Comment: You can share on Dropbox/box etc etc.  I won’t be able to help until maybe next week though